# Ubuntu 18 with Mate desktop HiDPI scaling messed up

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, mate, scaling, 4k-monitor

My laptop is running Ubuntu 18.04 and I use mate-desktop. (I login with gdm3, but I select Mate in the login window.) My laptop's built-in display is 4k. In mate-appearance-properties, I set DPI to 200, and everything looks great! Look at this screenshot. It's not just the fonts. Everything is scaled appropriately. The icons are bigger. The panel is bigger. Even the simple line that my window manager draws around the window borders is scaled from one pixel to two pixels (as xmag confirms). Hooray!

[Good Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJrxE.png)

I also have an external 4k monitor. When I hook it up and select "Mirror image on all displays", the external monitor looks exactly like the laptop display. They both look great. Hooray!

Then, in mate-display-properties, I turn off the laptop display. I want it to display *only* on the external monitor, and I want it to look *exactly* like it does when I mirror displays. But it doesn't. When I turn off the monitor display, the external display gets all screwed up. Look at this screenshot. The fonts are still big. The icons are small. The panel is... crashed?

[Bad Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsdZr.png)

I've been fighting this for quite a while. I've tried everything I can think of. Somehow, almost everything I try makes it worse. It feels like an accomplishment each time I manage to get back to "looks good when mirrored". Help?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the solution was to run mate-tweak and change HiDPI from Auto-Detect to HiDPI.